# Kendo UI Grid to Excel Format header in MVC 5

Tags: export-to-excel, kendo-ui-mvc

I can export excel to Kendo ui grid. But I want format header of file excel before export.

Answer (score 1):

To format the cell values, set the format option of the cells
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/excel/cell-format
Hope it will Help you.